# How to run multiple gradle tasks agains a subproject

Tags: gradle, gradlew

Usually for a normal project you can run multiple tasks in one line, doing something like:

```
./gradlew test clean
```

I tried the same for an specific subproject, but seems that I cannot do that anymore:

```
./gradlew :subprojects:subproject1:test clean
```

Is there any way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
./gradlew :subprojects:subproject1:test :subprojects:subproject1:test
```

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to the folder of the subproject and run your tasks

```
$ cd subprojects/subproject1
$ ./gradlew test clean
```